# Event Handling for Dynamically Created Activex Control

Tags: c++, com, mfc, activex, ole

The scenario:
 I have a TabCtrl in which I plan to place 1 ActiveX Control (myActXCtrl) in each Tab. The number of Tabs can increase dynamically. Hence, I have to create a new instance of ActiveX Control (myActXCtrl) each time and place it in the newly created Tab (I have done till this point successfully).

The problem:
    The ActiveX Control has some events using which it can notify me of the Clicks or selections made inside(on) the ActiveX Control. For this I need to have Event Sink in the control container to handle the events that are coming from ActiveX Control. (For a design time created ActiveX Control this works fine)

```
How do I HANDLE the events that are fired by the dynamically created ActiveX Controls?
```

[I know I cannot define Event Sinks for dynamically created ActiveX Contols]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can query the ActiveX for IConnectionPointContiner interface and hook events via IConnectionPoint